# Agile Toolkit 4.2 ... reference field type breaking with model

Tags: atk4

This is a simple re-write of the example code for a reference field:

```
class page_LoadResults extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();
    $p=$this;
    $f=$p->add('Form');

$c=$p->add('Model_Season');
$f->addField('reference','Season')
    ->setValueList($c)
    ->validateNotNull()
    ->add('Icon',null,'after_field')
    ->set('arrows-left3')
    ->addStyle('cursor','pointer')
    ->js('click',$f->js()->reload())
    ;
```

When called I get an error message:

\atk4\lib\Form/Field.php:652 [2] htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Looking at the code, around line 648 in Field.php

```
    foreach($this->getValueList() as $value=>$descr){
        // Check if a separator is not needed identified with _separator<
        $output.=
            $this->getOption($value)
            .htmlspecialchars($descr)
            .$this->getTag('/option');
    }
```

Is indeed apparently creating $descr as an array of ($value,descr)

IS this a bug or am I off base.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use atk 4.2 syntax

```
<?php

class page_b extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $p=$this;
        $f=$p->add('Form');
        $field = $f->addField('Dropdown','Season');
        $field->setModel("a");
        $field
            ->validateNotNull()
            ->add('Icon',null,'after_field')
            ->set('arrows-left3')
            ->addStyle('cursor','pointer')
            ->js('click',$f->js()->reload())
            ;
    }   
}
```

1. Pay attention to `addField("Dropdown")`
2. use `setModel` rather than `setValueList($model);`

Comment: Have you tested this?
It doesn't work with a table model.

Class Form_Field_ValueList defines the method setModel() which includes only the following code: $this->setValueList(array('foo','bar'));

Comment: it's the getValueList() method that then sorts things.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, the setModel function just calls the super method and then sets the valuelist to foo,bar. The dropdown list then contains nothing.

Comment: Okay, look, I have tested it (exact codes as above), and it is working smoothly with latest atk4 4.2 (master branch). try updating your atk4 version. As for previous comment, check class, Form_Field_ValueList, method getValueList. You will see that it will use model to fetch data, if model is present. that "$this->setValueList(array('foo','bar'));" is just for the case if model fails.  Also, check Form_Field_Dropdown-getInput method. You will see that it is using getValueList to fetch data (and that uses model if possible)

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Downloading the latest version from github has fixed it, not sure why but that doesn't matter.